# Find all projects that source dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, search

Is there an easy way to see all the MXDs that use data from a single file geodatabase (GDB) as their source using ArcCatalog? I'm not arcpy proficient. I feel like I've used a tool like this before, but can't find it anywhere. I've found ways to list data sources in a single project, but I want to do the reverse.

Comment: It would take a bit of effort writing something in arcpy, but the procedure would be something like this:  1.) use os.walk to iterate through a file structure.  2.) For each .mxd in the tree use the arcpy.listlayers and the layer.dataSource attribute.  3.) Compare the layer.dataSource attribute with the path of the dataset in question.  This could definitely work.  Hopefully this comment will at least point you in the direction of starting to learn what to do.  Arcpy can be a little daunting at first, but once you get the basics it will make GIS much more effective for things like this.